# Script to select

Tags: bash, awk, bioinformatics, genetics

I am working with GWAS data, trying to select linkage-disequilibrium independent loci. My approach is to rank all significant SNPs from most —> least significant, and then remove any SNPs that are in linkage disequilibrium (r2 > 0.2) with a SNP above them in the list in 1KG.

I have a file with my SNPs ranked from most --> least significant:

```
rs2021722
rs1117490
rs2844776
rs971570
```

I also have a file listing the SNPs that are in LD with each of these (from SNAP):

```
SNP  Proxy  Distance    RSquared    Chromosome  Coordinate_HG18
rs2021722   rs2021722   0   1.000   chr6    30282110
rs2021722   rs885912    502 1.000   chr6    30282612
rs2021722   rs971570    1618    1.000   chr6    30280492
rs2021722   rs2844776   2304    1.000   chr6    30279806
rs2021722   rs1117490   3621    1.000   chr6    30278489
rs1117490   rs1117490   0   1.000   chr6    30278489
rs1117490   rs2517610   230 1.000   chr6    30278259
rs2844776   rs971570    686 1.000   chr6    30280492
rs2844776   rs1117490   1317    1.000   chr6    30278489
rs971570    rs2021722   1618    1.000   chr6    30282110
rs971570    rs1117490   2003    1.000   chr6    30278489
```

I want to execute a script that will read the the SNP ID in the first file, find that SNP ID in the second file, and then read the "Proxy" column of the second file. If none of the proxy SNPs in the second file are in lower row numbers of the first file (ie. higher up in the file, with a better rank), I want the to write that SNP ID to my output file.

In this example, my output file would look like:

```
rs2021722
rs117490
```

I have some experience in awk and bash, but am very new to both and don't have a clue where to begin to complete this task. Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

Comment: please, write the output as an example, it will be better than explaining how he could look like, and easier for us to answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk 'FNR == NR {a[$1]=++n; next}
    FNR > 1 { b[$1] = (!b[$1] || (a[$2] && a[$2]<b[$1])) ? a[$2] : b[$1] } 
    END { for(i in b) if(a[i]<=b[i]) print i }
' file1 file2
```

Note:

- 1st line, rank the SNP ids from the first file and save the result to array 'a'
- 2nd line, get the highest rank (minimal non-empty value of a[$2]) for proxy id based on column-2 and save the result to array 'b'. (FNR>1 to skip the title line)
- 3rd line, print the keys which satisfies: a[i] <= b[i]

Comment: Assuming this outputs what the OP wants - +1!

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand what you're trying to do with the output file, but as for finding the SNP IDs in the second file from the first, you can use this.

```
while read line; do
    val="$line";
    echo "val: $val";
    while read line2; do
       val2=$(echo "$line2" | awk '{print $1}');
       if [ $val == $val2 ] ; then
           echo $val "=" $val2;
           proxy=$(echo "$line2" | awk '{print $2}');
           echo "proxy = $proxy";
       fi
    done < file2.txt
done <file1.txt
```

Basically it loops through the first file, then checks the second file if that line exists, if it does it grabs the second field (the proxy).  If you can better explain the output file thing I'll give that a shot.  This should get you going I think.

Comment: UNIX shell is an environment from which to call tools with a language to sequence those calls. The standard UNIX tool to manipulate the contents of text files is awk. SO, don't write shell loops to manipulate the contents of text files - just call awk. The solution will be briefer, clearer, faster, more robust and simply superior in every way.

Comment: I said manipulate the CONTENTS of text files. There may be a better way to describe the intent but I'm sure you get the idea - a shell loop just to work on text is the wrong approach.